# Is $f$ continuous on a contour $\Gamma$?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration

I am practicing for my midterm exam. I would appreciate it if someone could point me to any mistakes or flaws in my answer to this question I tried:

> Given a contour $\Gamma : |z-\pi|=\frac{\pi}{2}$ traversed once counterclockwise, and define for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ that are not on $\Gamma$ $$f(z) := \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma \frac{\cos \zeta}{\zeta - z} d\zeta $$
>   and for $z$ that are on $\Gamma$, $f(z) := 0$. Is $f$ continuous on $\Gamma$?

**My answer:** We take any point $z_0$ on $\Gamma$ such that $\cos z_0 \neq 0$. The function $f(\zeta)=\cos \zeta$ is analytic in the right half of the complex plane. Cauchy's integral formula then says that for any $z_0$ in the interior of $\Gamma$, $f(z)=\cos z$. For continuity, we must have that by whichever path we go, $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} f(z) = f(z_0)$. If $z$ approaches $z_0$ along a path in the interior of $\Gamma$, $f(z)=\cos z \rightarrow \cos z_0 \neq 0$. However, $f(z_0)=0$, as $z_0$ lies on $\Gamma$. This means $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} f(z) \neq f(z_0)$, so $f$ is not continuous on all of $\Gamma$.

---

I am especially unsure about my notation and way of writing everything down clearly. For example, I want to name $f(\zeta)=\cos \zeta$ since it fits perfectly in the Cauchy formula "form", but is that OK, or do I call it something else, for example $g(\zeta)=\cos \zeta$?
I feel a bit silly asking this sort of question, but I hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function $f$ has already been defined in the question, so yes, you should call your function something else, until you've *shown* that the two are equal.

Comment: OK, I will remember this.Thank you!

Comment: Also, I don't think the question is phrased quite right. It asks whether $f$ is continuous on $\Gamma$, but immediately before that $f$ is *defined* as being $0$ on $\Gamma$. And of course the zero function is continuous... Should the question be whether $f$ is continuous on the closed disk bounded by $\Gamma$?

Comment: Another small point on notation; you say *"for any $z_0$ in the interior of $\Gamma$, $f(z)=\cos(z)$."*. I think you mean $z$ in stead of $z_0$?

Comment: And for the actual proof itself; does there exists a point $z_0$ on $\Gamma$ such that $\cos z_0\neq0$ to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

My answer:
We take any point $z_0$ on $\Gamma$ such that $\cos z_0\ne 0$. 
Cauchy's integral formula says that 
$$f(z)=\cos z$$
for any $z$ in the interior of $\Gamma$. 
If $z$ approaches $z_0$ along a path in the interior of $\Gamma$, $$f(z)=\cos z \to \cos z_0 \ne 0$$
since $\cos z$ is continous on $\mathbb{C}$.
However $f(z_0 )=0$ by it's definition, as $z_0$ lies on $\Gamma$. This means $$\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)\ne f(z_0),$$ so $f$
is not continuous at $z_0\in \Gamma$. Therefore our conclusion is that the function $f(z)$ is not continous on $\Gamma$.